# Map two objects in an update query

Tags: dapper

Dapper is able to map this query to the `car` object. It knows which property in the car goes to which variable in the query.

```
Car car = new Car();
conn.Execute(
      "UPDATE CAR" +
      " SET COLOR=@Color,MODEL=@Model" +
      " WHERE ID=@Id", car;
```

But can I add another variable to the query? E.g:

```
int c = 1000; 
conn.Execute(
      "UPDATE CAR" +
      " SET COLOR=@Color,MODEL=@Model,COST=@cost" +
      " WHERE ID=@Id", car, new { cost = c };
```

I'd like to do this without having to match every property in the car object to a variable in the query. Here's the example class, but I have a lot more properties in my real class.

```
public class Car {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better answer but this worked for now:

```
int c = 1000; 
conn.Execute(
      "UPDATE CAR" +
      " SET COLOR=@Color,MODEL=@Model,COST=" + c +
      " WHERE ID=@Id", car;
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just create a new dynamic for all parameters. For example:

```
var car = new Car();
car.Color = "Black";
car.Model = "BMW";
car.Id = 123;
var cost = 53000

DbConnection.Execute(@"update car set color=@color, model = @model, cost = @cost where id = @id",
                new { color = car.Color, model = car.Model, cost = cost, id=car.Id});
```

This way you can assemble the dynamic from multiple objects/variables.